# Unity change the focused color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had an input Field in my game that was working great with Unity 2018.3

I'm using color tint and set the colors dynamically on the awake (depending on the style the user has selected).

I started working again on the game and upgraded my unity to the latest one (2019.2.x) and now when my input has the focus it's black (both text and target graphic)

I don't see any way to set the "focused color" using a color block?

How can I get rid of this black focused color to use my custom color?

Comment: Is it not the selected colour? maybe highlighted colour? show your settings for the field

Comment: sounds a bit like a bug/shader issue?

Comment: I don't use any custom shader, just the default one for UI

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for ColorBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ColorBlock.html) there is no property called "focused color". 
Your options are:

- Normal
- Highlighted
- Pressed
- Selected

Here is a little [gif example](https://gyazo.com/2c0d9c9bb4998b7c98303541af79b222) of what those all are in action.

It's important to remember that your Selectable's `ColorBlock` multiplies with your `Image` color property, so if you want your Color Tint transition to do most of the work, it should probably be white.  If that's black, everything will be black.

[image: Image of an Input Field where the Image Color has been set to black.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've set all the colors of my colorblock but when we are typing (so the input has the focus) the text becomes black even if none of the colors from the ColorBlock is black.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your Image, Text, and Input Field components?